# Pass value to anonymous function, function is within object value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a check to ensure that an object contains a value before returning it, however I can't seem to pass the value of 1 `this.map_options.map_type(1)` to the anonymous function as the `console.log` displays `undefined`.

```
MarvMap.prototype.init = function() {
    loadApi.call(this);

    // Setup map options and map reference
    this.mapReference = null;
    this.map_options = {
      map_type: function(i) {
        console.log(i);
        let x = [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4' ];
        if (x[i] !== undefined) {
          return x[i];
        } else { exit(this.errors.map_type(i)); }
      }.call(this)
    };

    build.call(this);
  };
```

This is how i'm attempting to retrieve the value from `map_options.map_type`.

```
console.log('MapType: ' + this.map_options.map_type(1));
```

Comment: `map_options` belongs to `MarvMap`, outside of it you cannot use `this.map_options`.

Comment: I have access to map_options, just removed the `.call(this)` and it appears to work. I think the `call` was making the function execute when the object is initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I managed it to work:

```
<script>
    function MarvMap (){
    }

    MarvMap.prototype.init = function() {
    // Setup map options and map reference
    this.mapReference = null;
    this.map_options = {
      map_type: function(i) {
        console.log(i);
        let x = [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4' ];
        if (x[i] !== undefined) {
          return x[i];
        } else {  }
      }.bind(this)
    };
  };

  var a = new MarvMap();
  a.init();
  console.log('MapType: ' + a.map_options.map_type(1));
</script>
```

You need to use `bind` instead of `call`.

Comment: Thanks, it's because I was using `call` instead of `bind` it appears.